# Кеширование картинок и css/js в nginx, вместе с django

Tags: django, nginx, кэширование, браузер

Не могу организовать правильное кеширование. 
При переходе на урл, вбиваю в адресную строку, естественно ничего не кешируется.
При обновлении страницы через ctrl+R или кнопокой в браузере, в кеширование ничего не уходит.
Если Я добавляю в конец урла "/" все полностью файлы тянутся из кеша.

Что Я делаю не так, почему при обычном обновлении всё не уходит в кеш, а при добавлении слеша, срабатывает?

Для тестирования всего этого использую chrome.

Конфиг прикрепил.

```
upstream app_server {
    server 127.0.0.1:9000 fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.html index.htm;

    client_max_body_size 4G;
    server_name _;

    keepalive_timeout 5;


    # Your Django project's media files - amend as required
    location /media  {
        alias /home/django/django_project/django_project/media/;
        expires max;
    }

    location /static {
        alias /home/django/django_project/static/; 
        expires max;
    }

    # Proxy the static assests for the Django Admin panel
    location /static/admin {
       alias /home/django/django_project/static/admin/;
        expires max;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_pass http://app_server;
    }
}
```

Comment: речь про кеш браузера или про кеш nginx-a?

Comment: @norbornen Я полагаю о кеше браузера. Но http заголовками рулит nginx ведь.

Comment: не понял про добавление "/", можете добавить примеры?

Comment: примеры с заголовками ответа для обоих случаев!

Comment: @norbornen http://i.gyazo.com/9f7c3be3a68731cbba57372587774cb8.png http://i.gyazo.com/3df7e90a0a3d452a36ce45f4f271b64a.png                         Первое соответственно без "/" в конце, а второе с "/", но он любом случае после редиректа пропадает. Мне кажется, что кеширование становится активным, при переходе по локальным местам(eg. /home). Но ведь на главной тоже должно отрабатывать, при обычном обновлении

Comment: @ashalbulk я ж просил заголовки... это не то. кстати, в обоих случаях написано, что берётся из кеша, хоть и статус ответа отличается. вставь директиву if_modified_since           before; на уровень http, рестартани nginx и показывай заголовки ответа для какой-то картинки для обоих случаев.

Comment: @norbornen заголовки http://i.gyazo.com/5d811541e2e1547a06d7cb4766d29fd2.png    http://i.gyazo.com/23692914f2b5d1110a5f963b40970f65.png                            Сейчас попробую if_modified_since before ещё

Comment: @norbornen вот с if_modified_since before; Но Я изменений не вижу. http://gyazo.com/b4268d6146c1fbc5920bb19353937cf8                          http://gyazo.com/74632decfbd8e78bf90c220bbcb02fd6

Comment: @norbornen а где Вы на первых скринах увидели, что в обоих случаях берёт из кеша?

Comment: @ashalbulk, я бы сказал, что вы немного неправильно интерпретируете увиденное. "а где Вы на первых скринах увидели, что в обоих случаях берёт из кеша" -> на первой картинке 304 статусы т.е. сервер сигнализирует браузеру что файл, который бр. хранит в кеше, не изменился и его можно брать из кеша (тут играют заголовки ETag и Last-Modified), на второй так и написано "from cache". А на какие адреса на вашем сайте можно смотреть?

Comment: @norbornen http://46.101.143.177/ кроме этого сайта больше ничего нет по урлу)

Comment: @ashalbulkz я спрашивал примерно: по каким адресам я могу увидеть первый и второй ответ

Comment: @norbornen 46.101.143.177 и 46.101.143.177/ соответственно. У меня получилось отправить в кэш картинки которые в css(background-image).

Answer (score 2):

На самом деле, все зависит не от слэша в конце - а исключительно от того, совершали ли вы переход по URL или обновляли страницу.

При переходе по URL браузер сразу же достает все картинки из своего кэша, о чем и пишет: *200 (from cache)*

В случае же обновления страницы браузер вполне резонно считает, что пользователю может не понравиться, если он возьмет картинки из кэша без единого запроса к серверу. Поэтому он отправляет запросы на сервер - но указывает в них версию кэшированных ресурсов. Сервер же, убедившись, что версия актуальна, отвечает браузеру кодом *304*, что означает разрешение использовать кэшированную версию дальше.

Коротко: обновление страницы отключает кэш браузера.